# How to print iteration value using pyspark for loop

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to print threshold for the dataframe values using pyspark.
Below is the R code which I wrote but I want this in Pyspark and I am unable to figure out how to do it in pyspark. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Values dataframe looks something like

```
values dataframe is

vote
0.3
0.1
0.23
0.45
0.9
0.80
0.36
```

```
# loop through all link weight values, from the lowest to the highest
for (i in 1:nrow(values)){
  # print status
  print(paste0("Iterations left: ", nrow(values) - i, "   Threshold: ", values[i, w_vote]))
}
```

What I am trying in pyspark is, but I am stuck here

```
for row in values.collect():
     print('iterations left:',row - i, "Threshold:', ...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every language or tool has a different way to handle things. Below I am providing answer in the way you tried -

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
[0.3],
[0.1],
[0.23],
[0.45],
[0.9],
[0.80],
[0.36]
], ["vote"])

values = df.collect()
toal_values = len(values)

#By default values from collect are not sorted using sorted to sort values in ascending order for vote column
# If you don't want to sort these values at python level just sort it at spark level by using df = df.sort("vote", ascending=False).collect()
# Using enumerate to knowing about index of row

for index, row in enumerate(sorted(values, key=lambda x:x.vote, reverse = False)):
     print ('iterations left:', toal_values - (index+1), "Threshold:", row.vote)

iterations left: 6 Threshold: 0.1
iterations left: 5 Threshold: 0.23
iterations left: 4 Threshold: 0.3
iterations left: 3 Threshold: 0.36
iterations left: 2 Threshold: 0.45
iterations left: 1 Threshold: 0.8
iterations left: 0 Threshold: 0.9
```

> It is not encouraged to use collect If you are dealing with big data it will break your program.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, its working. But As my dataframe is huge, How should i handle it, if its not recommended to use collect()

Comment: @Tilo it depends on what you want to achieve from it?